# SQLite Read Uncommitted in same transaction as write

Tags: c#, sqlite, transactions, system.data.sqlite

I'm using SQLite.Net from [sqlite.org](https://system.data.sqlite.org/)

I open a connection and begin a transaction. Inside the transaction I insert some rows. In the same transaction I attempt to read the data I have written which I expected to be the default (within the same transaction) however it does not seem to be the case.

I have open the database in WAL mode.

How can I read uncommited in the current transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this was my bad - I was actually reading on a different connection ...